# Is it possible to optionally use the docker COPY instruction?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm using the docker `COPY` instruction to copy files from `<src>` to `<dest>` as described in the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy). However it is possible that there will be no `<src>` file which causes `docker-compose build` to fail. Like so:

```
Step 7 : COPY cts/application.properties /cts/
ERROR: Service 'redirector' failed to build: lstat cts/application.properties: no such file or directory
```

Is there a way to only copy the file if it's there or turn off the errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to do that, is copying all files inside cts folder, for that, you can user `COPY` with a wildcard.

```
COPY cts/* /cts/
```

Or set your `WORKDIR`  as `cts`, copy all files, and then set back your `WORKDIR`

```
WORKDIR cts/
ADD . /cts/
WORKDIR old_workdir_path
```

But, if you want to copy conditionally one file using COPY command, you can't.